# How to configure Github actions to trigger Jenkins job running in my local machine

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have configured Jenkins in my local machine (Mac) to build a GitHub project. And I configured GitHub-webhook using ngrok. So for any push events, the Jenkins in my local machine is triggered successfully.

But now, I am thinking to remove ngrok as I have to reconfigure the webhook URL whenever I restart the machine.

I started learning about GitHub actions. But I couldn't find any examples to configure GitHub actions to trigger Jenkins job (via webhook or a particular job directly)

I tried the URL "https://github.com/appleboy/jenkins-action", but it seems, it will only work with docker Jenkins (because I received the error "Container action is only supported on Linux"), not with the local Jenkins.

Any suggestions would be helpful.